# Apache rewrite rule url parameters

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to capture all the parameters sent in the url and redirect pass it to a php file. Here is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET
RewriteRule ^/locations/(\w+\d*)+ /php/listone.php?name=$1 [L]
```

While this works correctly in the case when there are no white spaces in the url:

```
GET /locations/example HTTP/1.0
```

The $_GET['name'] in listone.php will contain example, but when I send

```
GET /locations/ex1 ex2
GET /locations/ex%20ex2
GET /locations/ex1+ex2
```

In listone.php I gave the following:

```
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 echo $name;
 $name = str_replace("+", " ", $name);
```

I will get just ex1. How can I capture all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your RewriteRule to this:

```
 RewriteRule ^/locations/(.+) /php/listone.php?name=$1 [L]
```

You aren't matching any character like white-space, `%` and `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a different apprach, and catch requests from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, and conditionally catch `$_GET` parameters, if needed.

Use this mod_rewrite snippet to achive this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /mydirectory/index.php [NC,L]
```

Just send a simple request, like:

> http://hostname.com/mydirectory/test/123

And echo the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable:

```
die($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // outputs: "/mydirectory/test/123"
```

In this way you can create a simple PHP router for your requestss